# Как и когда лучше выделить части речи в предложении?

Tags: морфемика, части-речи

Примеры:

Союз ЧТО/*что*, союз ЕСЛИ НЕ..., ТО / *если не..., то*;

Частица НЕ/*не*, частица ЧТО, ЕСЛИ / *что, если*;

Причастие НАЗЫВАЕМЫЙ/*называемый*;

Местоисение КАКОЙ-ЛИБО/*какой-либо*.

И таких примеров можно привести ещë очень много. Так же и с морфемами: приставка ПО-/*по-*, суффикс ЛИВ-/*лив* и т. д.

Хочется узнать, когда кавычки/курсив, а когда прописные.

Когда и как лучше писать? Или можно когда угодно использовать любой случай? Расскажите свое мнение по этому поводу.

Дополнено. Ещë есть такое: союз НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО(,) ЧТО / *несмотря на то(,) что*. В скобках указана возможность/невозможность запятой между частями союза. Эти скобки всегда нужно указывать или необязательно так делать?

Answer (score 0):

Выделение слов вообще, в т. ч. частей речи не предусматривает прописных. Штатных средств для выделения (курсив, жирный, курсив жирный, два типа кавычек) вполне достаточно: тексты в среднем, применительно к реалиям сайта, не превышают десятка фраз, да и перебор выделеных мест не помогает чтению. Иногда можно использовать и комбинации инструментов:

**Проход** — сочетание приставки «*про-*» и существительного «*ход*».

К вопросу о запятой. Взятие в скобки проблемного знака условно допустимо: их смысл понятен без слов. Когда же следом развёрнуто сообщается о только что визуально воспринятом, тогда приходит та мысль, что автор не представляет или равнодушен к тому, как воспринимается набранный им текст.